# GForge AS server management and admin

Tags: svn, gforge

My company is since a while using GForge AS to manage software development (trackers, time tracking). SVN server is linked to it for source code management.

The person that introduced GForge and managed it in the past is now gone from the company and unfortunately no knowledge transfer was done ! ...

I now need to add new users for brand new developpers that we just hired and of course I start to have issues. I am able with no issue to create users on the gforge side, however I can get these users to be able to connect to the svn repository...

GForge is running in a VMWare that I think is coming from the GForge website.

I have no clue where to start to find out how to solve my problems ! Any help or idea would be most appriciated !

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, I am doing some progress. I have found that the list of users and password is stored on /var/lib/gforge/svnroot-authfile. I have also found that the list of repository with the different user that can access it is stored in /var/lib/gforge/svnroot-access. So I guess I can had a user to these 2 files, but password are stored encripted ! How can I encrypt the password is then the remaining question ?

Comment: Some more progress! Looks like there is suppose to be some php cron job managing the transfer from GForge user to the svn... I have to figure out wich one, and why it is not running...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a temporary work around. Password encryption is done with php crypt() function. So I was able to encrypt the passwords and put them in the svnroot-authfile. It is far from automatic, but at least I have a solution !

Answer (score 0):

@Zangdar There are cron jobs that update the unix users, groups and permissions to match project memberships and privileges in GForge.  They should be listed in the crontab for the root user on the VM.

If you add a user to a specified project, into a role that has access to the SVN repository for that project, then their entry in svnroot-authfile and svnroot-accessfile should be updated automatically.  There might be a time delay while waiting for the cronjob to run.

In newer versions of GForge we have made these updates happen immediately when users are added or removed on projects.